Nissan Versa 2016
Hello I have a Nissan Versa 2016 1.6sv and I replaced the rotors and pads the premium gloss coat matching on correctly and my car is currently making a noise when I brake to a stop with a decline. It does a slight hummm then grind… any suggestions?
Thank you!

It sounds like you didn't follow the break-in instructions. Please find the instructions and follow them before trying to troubleshoot the problem.
One manufacturer of coated rotors wants you to completely wear off the rotor's coating on the braking surface by braking vigorously from 30 mph to 5 mph thirty times with cooling periods in between. Your instructions may differ.
